# PHP - include function directory path

Tags: php, web

I'm having trouble including a header in my website.
The code I'm using is:

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
```

The page that I'm including this PHP code on is a PHP page itself, so surely it should be working?

The page is located inside folders, e.g. "http://mydomain.com/stuff/morestuff/index.php"
Whereas on the FTP the header.php is located at "http://mydomain.com/header.php" - is this why it's not including the header file? Because it can't find it?

But when I do:

```
<?php include_once('http://mydomain.com/header.php'); ?>
```

There aren't any errors but the page is blank.

How do I fix this?
Basically, how do I include a header on my website?

How do I access the "header.php" file that is located at the root of my website directory?

Comment: <?php include_once('../../header.php'); ?>

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php include_once('../../header.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

include header.php like this

```
<?php include_once('/header.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to navigate two folder up from index script

```
<?php include_once('../../header.php'); ?>
```

You can always use `../` to navigate in upper folder.

From [**documentation**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

Comment: see my answer.. are you real?

Comment: So what? StackOverflow it's not a faster answer thing but a better answer. You didn't give any explanation as well...

Answer (score 0):

Use error_reporting(-1); and ini_set('display_errors', true); in the top of your main file in order to show all errors. There will be a PHP warning with detailed description why file isn't included

Answer (score 0):

I think that PravinS' answer should work. Your way is also correct, but I think that you maight have disabled allow_url_include in php.ini.

Just use /header.php, and leave allow_url_include option disabled for security reasons (unless you need it).